# Method for recoding all user-defined missing values from SPSS to NA during import in R?

Tags: r, import, spss, r-haven

I am using the haven package to import a large SPSS dataset into R. The dataset contains many variables with unique user-defined missing values--sometimes several for a single variable.

The date/time variables share `8888-08-08` and `9999-09-09` as user-defined missing values (signifying "Not Applicable" and "Unknown", respectively). Another set of variables related to ICD-10 codes contains `77777`, `88888`, and `99999` as missing values, indicating "Injured but Unknown Code", "Not Applicable", and "Unknown". Yet another set of variables contains the codes `66`, `77`, `88`, and `99` (for "Not Applicable", "Refused to Answer", "Variable Did Not Exist at Time of Collection", and "Unknown")... etc.

My question is whether there is an argument in haven (or another data loading package in R) that will automatically convert these various user-defined missing values to NA *during* the import process of the original SPSS file.

I have tried the following without success:

```
df <- read_sav("/path/to/file.sav", user_na = FALSE)
```

Comment: @JohnPolo Not quite. The solution helps with changing the missing values for POSIXct columns, but it's not a comprehensive solution to filling in NAs for the entire dataset. Ideally, I'd like to be able to replace user-defined missing values (from SPSS) with NA while importing the .sav file, rather than manually having to change missing values for individual variables once the dataset is loaded.